# Update args of a scheduled job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have scheduled a job

```
Worker.perform_at(time, args)
```

And I can fetch the scheduled jobs

```
job = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job(jid)
job.args # this is the args I passed above
```

I need to update the `args` that will be passed to the worker when it is called, i.e. update `job.args`. How do I do that?

This won't work:

```
job.args = new_args
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.to_a[0] = job
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well update the task is not the way achieving it cancel job and create new with new args:

```
job = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job(jid)
## time = job.time // Or just set time needed.
Sidekiq::Status.cancel jid

Worker.perform_at(time, new_args)
```

it will also make it easier for you to debug and log the jobs because when you edit/update them on the fly could cause bugs that very hard to identify.

Comment: For current readers, `Sidekiq::Status` is no longer maintained, but now you can just as easily do `job.kill`